# elasticsearch auto rebalancing of data across shards

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch.
Lets suppose I've 10000 documents. The relevant field in the documents are such that after getting indexed most of them would end up in a single shard.

Would ElasticSearch rebalance this "skewed" distribution for, may be better load balancing?

Comment: `most of them would end up in a single shard` are you using custom **routing**?

Comment: Lets say, 99% of them go to one particular shard because the relevant field in the document is like that.
My main focus in the question is to know if ElasticSearch will "redistribute" data to other shards to make it better "load balanced" ?

Comment: why was it downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you question right, the short answer - no, the documents will not be relocated. Choosing shard is based on modulo-like distribution, and its used for index as well as for retrieval.

So, if (theoretically) ES will rebalance such docs, you'll be unable to retrieve them with you routing key, as it will leads to original shard (which is empty in such theoretical case).

The ["distribution" part of docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/distributed-docs.html) if nice place for further reading

Comment: thanks, I was thinking the same when I was explaining it to someone, but didn't have a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you mean by this "the relevant field in the documents are such that after getting indexed most of them would end up in a single shard".

From what I understand, ElasticSearch will automatically balances the shards between all the nodes started on your setup to be the most effective possible.

The document are indexed on a shard with the field. The same document cannot have some fields on node 1 and some other fields on node 2.

Comment: shard = hash(routing) % number_of_primary_shards
Refer here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html

So, I meant the ID of the documents are such that almost all of them produce same `hash(routing)` value.